# How can i generate pages for some additional tasks other than CRUD by using Gii?

Tags: php, yii, gii

I have created one CRUD operation by using gii namely "Facilities". And i need to create one page for booking facilities. I need to make separate login for user who is booking facilities and admin who has to manage all booking made by users. Is it possible to create seperate pages by using gii for booking facilities, viewing booked facilities by the user himself and booked facilities by all the users?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if you mean that admin should be able to do all CRUD operations where other users can just create bookings, then you need to do that in `function accessRules()` in your controller.

Comment: can i use gii for creating facility booking page? can i populate facilities(which admin had created by CRUD Generator) in list box of the booking facility page?